# Casting to a generic type based on the concrete type of a parameter when only give its supertype

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I've been trying to write a method that given a parameter, it will return a new instance of a generic class whose generic type is based on the type of that parameter. Well, it'd be easier to illustrate with code.

First we have:

```
// Vehicles
abstract class Vehicle { }
class Car : Vehicle { }
class Airplane : Vehicle { }

// Containers for vehicles
abstract class VehicleContainerBase { }
abstract class VehicleContainer<T> : VehicleContainerBase where T : Vehicle { }

// One concrete container for each vehicle type
class CarContainer : VehicleContainer<Car> { }
class PlaneContainer : VehicleContainer<Airplane> { }
```

Now, I would like a method where you receive the supertype `Vehicle` - we don't know whether it's a `Car` or `Airplane` - but if it happens to be a `Car` it will return an object of apparent type `VehicleContainer<Car>`.

I know that I can simply return `VehicleContainerBase` and call it a day, but I wonder if it is at all possible to do it as I originally wanted. Here's the reproducible full code of my attempt:

(https://dotnetfiddle.net/TemdGk)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
    // Delegate representing the construction of a container
    delegate VehicleContainerBase CreateNewContainer();
    
    // Mapping types to their corresponding construction delegates
    private static Dictionary<Type, CreateNewContainer> mapping = new Dictionary<Type, CreateNewContainer>();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // "Register" the delegates so that they can be invoked as needed
        mapping.Add(typeof(Airplane), () => new PlaneContainer());
        mapping.Add(typeof(Car), () => new CarContainer());
        
        // Test it out
        var someCar = new Car(); // pretend we don't know this e.g. some API just returns Vehicle
        var carAsVehicle = (Vehicle)someCar;
        var theContainer = CreateContainer(carAsVehicle);
        Console.WriteLine(theContainer.GetType());
    }
    
    // This is the method that I'd like to build
    // I want the return type to be concretely VehicleContainer of the given parameter's type, instead of just VehicleContainerBase
    static VehicleContainer<VEHICLE_TYPE> CreateContainer<VEHICLE_TYPE>(VEHICLE_TYPE vehicle) where VEHICLE_TYPE : Vehicle
    {
        var createdContainer = mapping[vehicle.GetType()].Invoke();
        var castedContainer = (VehicleContainer<VEHICLE_TYPE>)createdContainer;  // <-- cannot cast
        return castedContainer;
    }
}

// Vehicles
public abstract class Vehicle { }
public class Car : Vehicle { }
public class Airplane : Vehicle { }

// Containers for vehicles
public abstract class VehicleContainerBase { }
public abstract class VehicleContainer<T> : VehicleContainerBase where T : Vehicle { }

// One concrete container for each vehicle type
public class CarContainer : VehicleContainer<Car> { }
public class PlaneContainer : VehicleContainer<Airplane> { }
```

Code fails at run-time with InvalidCastException:

> Unable to cast object of type 'CarContainer' to type 'VehicleContainer`1[Vehicle]'.

I thought that I could cast it to `(VehicleContainer<VEHICLE_TYPE>)` which would be translated to `(VehicleContainer<Car>)`, but that would not work.

Is there a way to implement this method so that the return type is how I hoped for originally in this example, or is my only option to change the signature and return `VehicleContainerBase` instead?

Thinking calmly, I don't think it's possible since the compiler can't guarantee that it can be cast... But I'm new to generics so maybe there is another way?

Comment: So you want to get ```VehicleContainer<Vehicle>``` in that ```cast``` or ```VehicleContainer<Car>```

Comment: @MichaelMao `VehicleContainer<Car>`

Comment: But you cast it to ```Vehicle``` it's now car now I think

Comment: @MichaelMao I cast it to `Vehicle` to demonstrate what I need. I want to get `VehicleContainer<Car>` when you're only given a `Vehicle` (but the actual type is `Car`). Seems like you need reflection in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know the resulting type at compile time you can't really define variable of that type...  So your only option is to use reflection (or `dynamic` which will implement correct reflection code for you):

```
dynamic theContainer = CreateContainer((dynamic)carAsVehicle);
```

Your attempt fails because type you ask to return does not match actual type of container that was created/found. If you want to return result of some base type instead of exact type of the container  `VehicleContainerBase` is indeed the safe option. Alternatively returning `null` on mismatch case could do. Finally, you may want to read on [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) and possibly get `IVehicleContainer<Vehicle>` to work.